# Is there a maximum number of pdas that can be owned by Solana account?

Tags: solana-program, pda, account

I am building an application and it is relatively heavy on the creation of PDAs.  I will be using a private cluster, so the cost of PDA creation is irrelevant.  But I am trying to understand the theoretical limitations of the program as I am architecting it, and the question arises....

Is there a maximum number of PDAs that can be owned by one account?  Is it U64?

Obviously there are other potential limitations that emerge when querying a large number of PDAs, so I realize this is not the only limiting factor that I should consider, but what is the value of this number?

Comment: This is an interesting question! I'm not an expert on cryptography, but since the address space in Solana is given as 32 bytes, ie a u256, and PDAs are valid for roughly 50% of those values, you should theoretically be able to do `u255::MAX` PDA accounts. But I'm only adding this as a comment because a real cryptographer would likely have a better answer. The Solana network has no ownership limits.